# Using Nodejs to stream output as keyboard input in OSX application

Tags: node.js, macos, stream

In my node programme (as a node newbie), I am translating midi values from a piano keyboard to A-Z letters. The idea is to be able to write emails etc using my piano keyboard.

How can I get the values that are written to console using

```
process.stderr.write(letterValue);
```

to appear as a key press input in another programme, such as Gmail / TextEdit, when I change window focus to that application?

Is process.stderr the right approach? Currently the letterValue variable is written to console only.

Answer (score 1):

You may try an alternative to kbm-robot. It is a very small and still cross platform library to send keys to your operational system called node-key-sender.

Install it with `npm install --save-dev node-key-sender`.

And send an enter key to the keyboard using:

```
var ks = require('node-key-sender');
ks.sendKey('enter');
```

Check out the documentation page to see how to send other keys: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-key-sender.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - how to make create system wide input in node:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/kbm-robot